# Tomcat 6 Classloader : Which Jar is it reading?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jar, classloader

I have a huge web application that I have to support. Recently when I downloaded the latest source from SVN and try to run it locally on Tomcat 6, I get the following error from one of the background batch jobs that the application runs...

```
2014-12-23 18:08:27 [taskScheduler-4] TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler [ERROR] Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory.newFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory;
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor$HeadersProcessor.<clinit>(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:275)
```

So I believe the problem is the Apache class ReadHeadersInterceptor which my application's code calls is trying to call the newFactory() method from XMLEventFactory but is not finding that method, probably because it is reading an older version of XMLEventFactory.

I think this is happening because there are some JARs in my lib folder I need to remove or add. Problem is I don't know which one. I see there are several JARs which have XMLEventFactory including..

woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0
stax2-api-3.1.1

And it is also part of Java 6 in the rt.jar.

So out of all these Jars which one is it trying to read and not find that method it needs?

Thanks.

Comment: Java EE app servers have a hierarchy of class loaders: bootstrap, app server, application server.  If it's in the rt.jar, that should be loaded first.  That JAR might be in the JVM or the app server.  Check those for conflicts with your application.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with specific version of JDK/JRE 1.6 (I mean the update). It may looks weird but the JDK API change for specific major version.

Please take a loot at the following [link](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/compat_reports/jdk/1.6.0.17_to_1.6.0.18/src_compat_report.html#Added). You can see there that with change from version 1.6.0.17 to 1.6.0.18 the new methods have been added on the **XMLEventFactory** class.

Probably you have the JRE version less thank 1.6.0.18. I've had the same problem with Apache CXF and dynamic proxies. The update of JRE 1.6.0.14 to 1.6.0.19 fixed the issue.

I hope it helps.